# WSUS variables and LanSafe Client install

Tags: windows-update, wsus

I have a WSUS / EminentWare server that I would like to use to push out the LanSafe 6 client to my servers.

This installer is horrible. I need a way to hardware the path to the configuration file.

Is the installation directory *for any random windows update, while the installer is actually running* - always C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\Install? It appears to be when I look at this empirically however I haven't found any reliable documentation on this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attempted to use the C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\Install path. 
It is functioning in all of my test cases.